# Realtime blur for video

Tags: c#, video, filter

I need a blur algorithm which runs within 50 milliseconds and uses minimal RAM, so that I can use it in realtime video. Firstly, is this even possible in C# or a .NET compatible framework? Efficiency is key.
I have tried the AForge Gaussian filter, and it is far too slow. The box blur from vcskicks is faster, but not fast enough.
Thanks

EDIT: Is there no way at all to apply a fast box blur, such as unsafe code, in .NET?

Comment: I suppose that depends on the resolution of your video...

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way C# and .NET handle memory allocation and garbage collection, it would be very difficult to get an implementation that would operate on realtime video with no lagging / framedrops.  You're probably better off looking at other technologies for this sort of thing.

Comment: Such as CUDA? If so, I have never used it

Comment: Can you explain what about memory allocation and GC makes this difficult? It sounds pretty interesting.